# force column size to smallest possible

Tags: html, html-table, column-width

I have a table with information in it and an icon in the last column that perfoms a function. I was wondering if it were possible to force that column to be as small as possible (i.e. as wide as the icon). Currently it has a fair bit on white space that i cant get rid of. I have tried setting the width tp 1% and 1px. How to i force it smaller?

Thanks

Comment: post your actual HTML + screenshot. Just as an off chance, try adding cellspacing=0 and cellpadding=0 attributes and see if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table width is set to 100%, no? Try adding another column after your icon column with blank cells and see if that does not take some of the extra width away.

Comment: I dont want to take away from this column i want to give that space to another column that needs it.

Comment: Then you can set the width on every TD like width="*" and the width attribute of the last column to your desired value.

Answer (score 1):

Set width for TD tag as same as width for IMG tag(icon), like this code: `<td width="16"><img width="16" ... />`